# Can I initialise an object of a derived class in another derived class?

Tags: c++

Can I initialise an object of a derived class in another derived class (where both classes are derived from the same base class) in C++? I want to do this as I want to overload the >> operator to enable me to populate derived_class_a's base class pointer vector with objects of derived_class_b.

Thanks

E.g.

```
class base_class
{
}

class derived_class_a : base_class
{
}

class derived_class_b : base_class
{
derived_class_a variable{};
}
```

Comment: yes? why wouldn't this work?

Comment: @user253751 I realised in my code I defined the derived_class_a after derived_class_b so couldn't make an object of it in derived_class_1. I've now changed the order and it works :)